# Set start page depending on screen width

Tags: theme-development, jquery, javascript, responsive

I'm building a responsive theme and would like to have different start pages depending on screen width.

In this case, the start page is set in WP admin and contains an image map built on a cunstom page template. On mobilde devices this image map doesn't work so well, so I'd like set one of the other pages as start page.

I guess I can merge front-template with standard-template and somehow achieve this with media queries, but would prefer a javascrip/jQuery solution.

Thanks

Comment: PHP has no idea what the screen width is since it runs on the _server_ before content is sent to the client.

Comment: ah of course.. So jQuery solution then?

Comment: Media queries and/or Javascript, yes.

Comment: Altered question. On topic?

Comment: Please explain why this is off topic?

Comment: Your question, and the plausible solutions, are purely CSS and Javascript. While the problem may appear in a WordPress context there is nothing specifically WordPress about it.

Comment: Alright. Suppose this comment is even more off topic then :), but here goes: Can't be such a wild idea having different start pages depending on width. Yes, you can code it in a template and use media queries. But it would not be av very generic solution. If you change your mind you will have to recode your template. Also can't see an answer in a javascript forum easily implemented i a WP environment without being a fairly good programmer. But I may be wrong of course. Anyhow, thanks for your time :)

Comment: I think I'm going to rephrase this question and go for a fresh start (new question).

Comment: @BoBoz The on topic answer is use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/mobble/ it gives you php functions like is_mobile(), is_iphone, etc. Its awesome. I'd explain fully, but its forbidden...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard for PHP to know your screen width. It's more of a job for jQuery. But your approach seems kind of backward. If the site is supposed to be responsive -- why are you trying to deliver *different* pages to your visitors based on screen width?

It would seem you should handle varying content via [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

So if you have 5 pieces of content... let's say

1. Header A - intended for desktop
2. Header B - intended for mobile
3. Content - same for all
4. Footer A - intended for desktop
5. Footer B - intended for mobile

You would **hide** the mobile (B) components when screen width is greater than X, and **show** the desktop (A) components.

Conversely, when screen width is less than X, you would do the opposite: **showing** mobile components (B) and **hiding** desktop components (A).

Make sense?

Comment: I just want another start page when screen width is below like 768 px. Not many start pages for several diffrent widths. Also this is rather late in development, so instead of reorganize templates I'm lookng for a smart way. jQuery?

Comment: Ok, this seems not to be doable the way I was thinking. As such, all possible front end content will reside in the same template and be organized by media queries. Your answer is correct.